# the argument on on click function is not defined in react

Tags: reactjs

hey so i  have trying to watch some tutorial, but i have encountered a problem,

```
handleIncrement = (product) => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <img src={this.state.imageUrl} alt="" />
        <span style={this.styles} className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>
          {this.formatCount()}
        </span>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        {this.state.tags.length === 0 && "Please create a new tag"}
        {this.renderTags()}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

the product on onClick function in the render section is not defined, but the  tutorial i follow on youtube when he write this code, it work just fine for him, any help please?

this is the video i watch  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0  , on 1:15:39

can i dinamically take the value of product from handleIncrement?

thank you.

Comment: Why did you comment out the variable product? `//const product = 1;`

Comment: Can you please add your entire code complete code ??

Comment: already have my answer, still i greatly appriciate you help guys, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because in the render method, there is no reference to the product for it to pass as an argument. So you need to pass the product in the argument of that method itself like below:

```
onClick={(product) => this.handleIncrement(product)}
```

Now it has something which he can pass ahead as an argument.

Comment: ahhh i see so that how you pass an argument on inline function(thats what it called right..?), thank you very much, appricate the help :D

Comment: @HyrorHakeith Please mark this answer as accepted if that solved your issue. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You should uncomment out the variable you're trying to use:

```
const product = 1;
```

Comment: but if i do that, it will stuck on 1, can i just take the value of product from handleIncrement? because that what he do in the video

Comment: i have tag the video i have mention and the hour too, please take a look, or is that way is outdated or something? appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I re-watched the video, and **Even for him it will be not defined**, he tried the code when he passed `{id: 1}`, but after that, he demonstrated that, in a real-world application, you will not pass the object statically like `{id: 1}`, but you will pass it like `product` `user` `category`, etc... (just for example as he said)

Hope that answered your question.

Comment: ahhh i see so that was only an example, thank you very much for the help. sorry still kinda try to grasp the good concept of using react.